# Sequelize CLI migration error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'detail')

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm running `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate` to create the table in the database and returns the following message:

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 18.9.1, CLI: 6.5.1, ORM: 6.20.1]


ERROR: Cannot find "/src/db/migrations/config/config.json". Have you run "sequelize init"?

ERROR: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'detail')
sequelize-cli db:migrate

Run pending migrations
```

But I have already run the command sequelize-init...

this is my config.js file

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

export default {
  development: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    logging: true,
  },
  test: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
  },
  production: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
  },
};
```

My migration file:

```
"use strict";

/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable("Users", {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      birth_date: {
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(62),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      phone: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      address: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      position_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: "Position",
          key: "id",
        },
      },
      is_active: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      is_admin: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  },

  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("Users");
  },
};
```

my .sequelizerc file:

```
import path from "path";

export default {
  config: path.resolve("config", "config.js"),
};
```

and my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-gh-pages",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test",
    "dev": "nodemon src/server.js"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-ejs-layouts": "^2.5.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "http-error": "^0.0.6",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sequelize": "^6.20.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.5.1"
  }
}
```

I would like to perform the migration but I couldn't succeed, even if I changed the config file to json, and the error still persisted...

Comment: if you are using typescript and get this exact error, all your ts files need to use require module.exports instead of import export, learned this the hard way of burning 24 hrs

Comment: im using nodejs vanilla not Typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the config/config.js,

- did you try to use `const dotenv = require('dotenv');` instead of `import dotenv from "dotenv";` ?
- replacing `export default` by `module.exports =` ?

Comment: Yes, i only can use the sequelize with require/module.exports, do you know if Sequelize don't support ES6 imports? 
Because of this errors i was thinking about it...

Comment: As for me, the ES6 imports were the issue as it was not supported by sequelize. Maybe verifying the other files using sequelize would unblock you.

Answer (score 3):

In your models/index.js file, you need to update config.json to config.js

Comment: This question has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer

Comment: His error: "ERROR: Cannot find "/src/db/migrations/config/config.json". Have you run "sequelize init"?"
Then he proceeds to say: "this is my config.js file"
Which means he changed config,json to config.js
We can also conclude this from the fact that he used env vars in config (which do not work in json files, only js files)

But he forgot one thing. When you do that, in your models/index.js file, you need to change config.json to config.js

Answer (score 0):

run the following command would do the trick

`npx sequelize-cli db:migrate --debug`

for me, i missed a `,` in my migration file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate` inside the correct folder where ".sequelizerc" is located

It worked for me, I was trying to run the command in a previous folder, that's why it was giving an error